# Internationalization of toString() method

Tags: java, internationalization

In my model class, I have overridden the toString() method and the contents of the toString method is given below.

```
getQueryName() + " -" + (getCriticalities().isEmpty() ? "" : " <b>Criticalities:</b> " + getCriticalities())
                        + (getCompletions().isEmpty() ? "" : " <b>Completions:</b> " + getCompletions()) + (getPriorities().isEmpty() ? "" : " <b>Priorities:</b> " + getPriorities())
                        + (getUrgencies().isEmpty() ? "" : " <b>Urgencies:</b> " + getUrgencies())
                        + (getHistorical().isEmpty() || getHistorical().equals("None") ? "" : " <b>Historical:</b> " + getHistorical())
                        + (getPlannerGroups().isEmpty() ? "" : " <b>Planner Groups:</b> " + getPlannerGroups())
                        + (getWorkOrderNumbers().isEmpty() ? "" : " <b>Work Order Number:</b> " + getWorkOrderNumbers())
                        + (getWorkCenters().isEmpty() ? "" : " <b>Work Centers:</b> " + getWorkCenters());
```

I have to change words like criticalities, completions in the language that the user has selected. I already have property files for languages. But as it is an entity class, I am unsure of how to change it.

Comment: I would __not__ bother putting any internationalization into a `toString()` mtehod. It should be used for stuff like logging, not for display to the end user. Handle the language specific stuff in the view layer instead.

Comment: In the view layer i am using BeanItemContainer which displays this string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:
 Return language keys instead of literals in toString method, and then use bundle.getString(object.toString())

Or asign the key to a variable and then use bundle.getString(variable) inside the toString method.

Comment: I have  a bundle class in my project. How to create a object of bundle class in an entity class?

Comment: ResourceBundle bundle = PropertyResourceBundle.getBundle("bundleName", locale)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are running into "separation of concerns" problem.
In an ideal world, it is a view that is responsible for I18n, i.e. resolving translations. Is there any specific reason why your model should be language aware?
Personally, I don't think so. You should keep your models as language-independent as possible and format all the numbers, as well as translate all the messages in your views.

One thing to note here: if things like `Criticalities` needs translation and there are not too many items, it usually makes sense to use enums rather than strings (using strings in programming logic is considered bad practice, by the way).
If you have to use a specific object, it may make sense to add a specific identifier that you can later use to resolve the translations (in `ResourceBundle` look-ups). Sometimes you can use object values, but this will decrease the translation quality, as translators needs context (and the easiest way to provide context is bring it in a translation key).